# Laravel validation on update

Tags: php, laravel

When I want to update a user this are my rules:

```
private function validateUser(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $user = [
            'firstname'             => 'required|string|max:60',
            'lastname'              => 'required|string|max:60',
            'phonenumber'           => 'required|string|max:20',
            'email'                 => 'required|unique:user,email,'.$id,
            'company_id'            => 'required|integer',
            'role_id'               => 'required|integer'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $user);

        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return $validator->errors();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But the  `'email'  =>'required|unique:user,email,'.$id,` part is not working the way I want. Because right now when I update a user I receive the json message:

```
{"user":{"email":["The email has already been taken."]}}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi, what is the `$id` variable in the validation rules?

Comment: And second thing, I suppose that the error is thrown when the user doesn't change his email when editing his account? But everythings' works when he changes it?

Comment: @EL_Matella $id is the id from the user I want to update. And yes the error is there when the user doesn't change his email.

Comment: Are you sure that the table is `user` and not `users`?

Comment: @EL_Matella yes I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private function validateUser(Request $request,$id)
{
    $user = [
        'firstname'             => 'required|string|max:60',
        'lastname'              => 'required|string|max:60',
        'phonenumber'           => 'required|string|max:20',
        'email'                 => 'required|unique:user,id,$id',
        // otherwise you can do the following
        'email'                 => 'required|unique:user,id,{{Auth::user()->id}}',
        'company_id'            => 'required|integer',
        'role_id'               => 'required|integer'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $user);

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return $validator->errors();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That's ok only if you want to update the current logged in user data.. what's happening if you want to update another user's data? .. I think a better way would be to use `$request->id` and to make sure that the route is requiring the ID

Comment: As of my knowledge, `id,$id` this is to check, if the email is unique or not (except the checking to be done for the current logged in user). Otherwise for the non-logged in user, anyway, we have to make the `email` field as `UNIQUE` in DB table.

Comment: @jamie, yes then what's the issue now? `'email'                 => 'required|unique:user,id,$id',` you can use this one for your convenience. Instead of `email,'.$id,`, use `id,$id` and hope this one will work.

Comment: How is this line working: `'email' => 'required|unique:user,id,{{Auth::user()->id}}',`?